# Common beforeInsert and beforeUpdate methods from Mixin for common domain columns

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, mixins

Most of the domain objects our company uses will have some common properties. These represent the user that created the object, the user that last updated the object, and the program they used to do it.

In the interest of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)ing out my domain classes, I want to find some way to add the same beforeInsert and beforeUpdate logic to all domain classes that have these columns without interfering with those that don't.

How I'd *like* to do it is using a [Mixin](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-mixin-functionality-to.html) with its own beforeInsert and beforeUpdate methods. I know [you can use Mixins on domain classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274461/1524502).

```
package my.com

import my.com.DomainMixin

@Mixin(DomainMixin)
class MyClass {
    String foo
    String creator
    String updater

    static constraints = {
        creator nullable:false
        updater nullable:false
    }
}


package my.com
class DomainMixin {
    def beforeInsert() {
        this.creator = 'foo'
        this.updater = 'foo'
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        this.updater = 'bar'
    }
}
```

Unit tests would indicate that the beforeInsert method isn't actually getting fired when implemented this way.

Side note:
I also know it's possible [to add the methods in a BootStrap.groovy file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280340/grails-domain-beforeinsert-beforeupdate) using the metaClass, but my curiosity has gotten the better of me and I really want to see if the mixin works. Feel free to tell me that this is the better way to do it and I ought not muddle where man ought not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI, use of `groovy.lang.Mixin` is strongly discouraged (by the Groovy project leader, for one). If you have to use mixins you should use `grails.util.Mixin` instead. One thing I don't like about your mixin approach is the implicit and unenforced assumption that the target of the mixin has `creator` and `updater` properties

Personally, I would probably just use plain-old inheritance for this, e.g.

```
abstract class Audit {

    String creator
    String updater

    def beforeInsert() {
        this.creator = 'foo'
        this.updater = 'foo'
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        this.updater = 'bar'
    }

    static constraints = {
        creator nullable: false
        updater nullable: false
    }
}
```

any domain classes that need to be audited would simply extend `Audit`. An alternative (and preferable) approach would be to use a [trait](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0/html/documentation/core-traits.html) rather than an abstract base class, but you'll need to be using a fairly recent Grails version in order to do this.

Comment: Inheritance seems reasonable to me. I'll just change my mixin in src/groovy to an abstract class and use extends. I'd love to use traits, but we're not quite up to the latest Grails yet.

Also, I noted this in an edit, but for this to work you need a beforeValidate() method that populates the required fields creator and updater, or beforeInsert and beforeUpdate never get called.

Comment: Just as an update, inheritance creates some issues with unit testing the domain that I have yet to resolve... mostly because the example here hides the complexity of my actual implementation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048179/unit-testing-grails-domains-that-over-extend-a-base-class-that-uses-services

Comment: Summary from above link: Groovy's `@Delegate` method was the answer. I imagine Traits would be even prettier, but for now, I'm happy with using the `@Delegate` annotation to bring in a class with a beforeValidate method.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mixins you can use the **Event Bus** of the [Grails Platform plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/events.html) to make your app more DRY. The plugin supports adding listeners to [GORM events](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/events.html#gorm) and they can be applied to any given class or interface instance. You can also *attach more than one listener* and write more concise unit tests.

If you want to share some logic accross domains, they must implement an interface and then create a service with the following method:

```
// domainService.groovy

@grails.events.Listener(namespace='gorm')
def beforeInsert(DomainInterface domain){
    domain.creator = 'foo'
    domain.updater = 'bar'

    // If the method returns false, then domain.save() won't be called. 
}
```