# GORM global beforeInsert to set modifiedBy

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I want to set the modifiedBy and createdBy properties of my DomainClasses automaticly.
For that i changed the Bootstrap.grooy to this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass

class BootStrap {
def grailsApplication

def init = { servletContext ->
    grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { GrailsDomainClass gdc ->
        if (gdc.hasProperty('modifiedBy') && gdc.hasProperty('createdBy')) {
            gdc.metaClass.beforeInsert = {
                modifiedBy = springSecurityService.currentUser.id
                createdBy = springSecurityService.currentUser.id
            }
        }
        if (gdc.hasProperty('modifiedBy') && gdc.hasProperty('modified')) {
            gdc.metaClass.beforeUpdate = {
                modified = new Date()
                modifiedBy = springSecurityService.currentUser.id
            }
        }
      }
   } 
 }
```

To get this work i need springSecurityService in all the DomainClasses that have the properties, I could add this:

```
def springSecurityService
static transients = ['springSecurityService']
```

How can i inject the springSecurityService without that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954272/common-beforeinsert-and-beforeupdate-methods-from-mixin-for-common-domain-column)

This works with the [Platform Plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/events.html)